# Unit testing a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller

I have a very simple `UIViewController` with a `UITextField` that takes some data, and a button. If the data is invalid then a `UIAlertView` is displayed when the button is pressed.

Using `OCMock`, I have written a unit test that mocks the `UIAlertView` and confirms that the alert view is shown when if the name is invalid.  Also simples.

The problem is, I cannot get any text into the `UITextField` from in the unit test.  In the code snippet below, there are no compilation or runtime errors (so the view controller is being instantiated) but the output is always "Data is (null)".  Any ideas? (I'm sure it must be something simple.)

```
ViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil]
                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    controller.data.text = @"123";
    NSLog(@"\n\nData is = %@\n\n", controller.data.text);
    // Outputs: Data is (null)
```

Comment: Just to be sure.. controller is non null and data is also non null and data is a textfield?

Comment: Yes, controller is not null (good call, I added another log statement to confirm that).  data is a UITextField.

Comment: Ah, controller.data is null.  Well spotted.

Comment: controller.data, this text field might not be linked properly if it is through xib.

Comment: The solution is to load the view after instantiating the controller [controller loadView].